# gridview image drag and drop

Tags: java, android

i alredy making gridview with image, now i want make my gridview image can drag and drop between gridview if i can, anyone can help? i m still learning but i want make prototype my app android, and that prototype can drag and drop between gridview. please

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    }
    else
    {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};
}



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Drag And Drop Framework.

> [Drag And Drop](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

Basically it not too complicated, but you need to define what exactly you want to do.

Example:

```
gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final ClipData dragData = new ClipData("dragLabel", new String[]{ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN}, null);
            view.startDrag(dragData,  // the data to be dragged
                    new View.DragShadowBuilder(view), // the drag shadow builder
                    null,
                    0          // flags (not currently used, set to 0)
            );
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Then you define listener to the DragEvent that you want to receive the dragEvents and manage the DragEvent.ACTION_DROP event for your needs.

Comment: i want my gridview can drag and drop, but i don't know how to do that cause when i see the example it only single image without gridview

Comment: I edited the answer for you so you understand the direction of how to adjust  the examples in the docs for your needs.

Comment: sorry for trouble i m still don't understand

Comment: what you don't understand?

Comment: yes, cause i m still new at android, don't know where i must place that code, sorry...

Comment: Just below     gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
in your code. But you can't expect that I Will write the whole code for you. You asked a question and received answer. Now you should accept the answer (unless you think it wrong) and ask new question about specific problems you run into. You can't just say "I'm new to android" and expect that others will feed you with spoon.

Comment: @shahak sorry about that

Comment: No problem, not meant to be offensive